# what is the network structure like in a cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a very hard time understanding what kubernetes network architecture is really like.

As a basic understanding "there's a machine behind each IP", but with this stuff of containers inside pods inside nodes inside a cluster hosted somewhere.

Adding services, deployments and other kubernetes objects, makes it even more confusing. The documentation is not super clear on that. I'm just lost and throwing hands in the air

Could I ask for a brief explanation of what network is inside what network, and what elements have IPs and/or ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"there's a machine behind each IP"

i am not sure about for which IP you are talking about

There are multiple components in Kubernetes if we focus main

- POD (It runs docker container)
- Deployment
- Service
- Ingress

Now if talk about managing the traffic it's work like

Ingress > ingress controller > Service > deployment > POD > Container

There are IPs assigned to each **PODs** (workloads)

But it's not useful in normal case, it auto managed by K8s nothing to do it with it.

it will be internal IP so you can not connect with workload of POD from out of Kubernetes.

Now we have Type of **Services**

- ClusterIP
- Load Balancer
- Node Port

Cluster IP is the same again internal IP managed by Kubernetes.

The load balancer is exposed to the internet it's like you are attaching the LB to your workload or application so it will be exposed to the internet.

In this case, you will get the external IP open to the internet.

This was like intern arch.

If we talk about simple cluster architecture

There are **master node** and **work nodes**

Work nodes have internal and external IP based on you Private Kubernetes cluster or Public Kubernetes cluster.

Each of you container or POD runs on worker node and have internal IP in ideal scenario.

Multiple workloads or containers can run on a single Machine or single VM NODE.

Ports get used the same way we use generally.

For example this is my test service :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 9595
  - name: https
    port: 9595
    targetPort: 9595
  selector:
    app: test
    tier: frontend
```

it's has exposed two port 80 and 9595. if you look carefully `targetPort: 9595` there is a target port in both cases it is diverting traffic to the **9595** port on which my container or workload will be running.

Comment: About nodes and pods having IPs, K8s network model(https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/) specifies "pods on a node can communicate with all pods on all nodes without NAT". But a node has, I suppose, an internal network with each of its pods inside it, so how does it go if I want to reach pod P2 in node N2 from pod P1 in node N1 ? It's confusing, is there like a private network for each node?

Comment: for that you can use the service layer. you can use service name as host name so that it will auto manage to routing at node and pod level.

Comment: For simple understanding : you are running two pod of your app one in node N1 and another one in N2.

Comment: Now if you hit curl request to the service `test` or whatever name you have set it will auto load balance traffic to these pods. you don't have to worry about IP and all, just use the IP of service or name of service and it will divert the traffic to PODs automatically.

Comment: And where do nodes' internal IP even matter? if the service is going to do the job to divert towards the right pods, why would I bother about a node having an internal ip?

Comment: It depends on scenarios node internal IP may matter but in very general scenario, it's not useful frequesntly.

Comment: You are running your application and database on the same Kubernetes cluster. your can also call your database by service like `mysql-database` in background it will auto resolve the IP. your app2 want to call app1 just use service name and you are done.

Comment: Please feel free to contact me anytime if you still have any doubts.

Comment: Hello, sorry for bothering you. I have this problem: I have a container which is internal, it's not served through a svc, but it makes requests to a svc that serves a rest api on port 9000. When I send requests to the svc dns or an ingress that redirects to the svc, I get "502 bad gateway" (it's in ClusterIP mode, and I also expose it to the internet with an ingress rule), but if I try the pod that's hosting the rest api, like so: http://pod.ip:9000 it works like a charm. strangely it also works if I make request from my computer to the rest api through the ingress rule(http://example.com/api)

Comment: @Sheed in svc dns are you providing the full proper path with namespace and everything  ?

Comment: I tried the full and the short url (smth like my-svc or my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster-url.com). I get "connection refused" now.
I tried to `curl my-svc:9000` inside the container, got connection refused. If I `curl http://my-svc:9000` 1 time out of 2, I get an http debug page from my django rest, and the other time a "connection refused".
If I use `host my-svc` from my container, I do get the clusterIP of my svc

Comment: this is a really weird issue but if we see connection refused only possible from service side instead of DNS

Comment: Hmm, Ok thank you for your insight, I'll try to see to it :) Hopefully this can be resolved soon, I've been stuck on this since yesterday